# Probability that a geometric Brownian motion with additional determinstic drift ever hits zero

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, and let $X_t$ be the solution to the following SDE

$$dX_t = (\mu X_t - Cke^{-kt}) \, dt + \sigma X_t \, dW_t$$

where $\mu, \sigma, C, k > 0$ are constants, with initial condition $X_0 = x_0 > C$ a.s.

**Question:** For fixed $T > 0$, can we estimate, or compute the probability

$$\mathbb P(\underset{0 \leq t \leq T}{\text{min}} X_t \leq  0)?$$

That is, the probability that $X_t$ ever hits zero before time $T$.

As suggested by Kurt G. in the comments, this SDE has an explicit solution, which may be helpful in estimating the given probability.

The explicit solution is given by

$$X_t = e^{\mu t + \sigma W_t-\sigma^2t/2} \left (x_0 - \int_0^t e^{-\mu s - \sigma W_s+\sigma^2s/2}\,Cke^{-ks} ds \, \right ) $$

**Remark:** I tried to apply Girsanov’s theorem to remove the drift, but the conditions for the density process $Z_T$ to be a martingale are not satisfied, due to the determinstic term blowing up when $X_t$ is small.

Comment: Hint : this SDE has an [explicit solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Linear_SDE:_general_case). Please write it down and add it to the question. Then we go from there.

Comment: Thank you! I have added the explicit formula.

Comment: I think something needed to be fixed a bit. Did it. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the component $Y_t=e^{\mu t +\sigma W_t-\sigma^2 t/2}$ of the explicit solution never hits zero. This boils down the problem to the question if
$$
Z_t:=\int_0^t\frac{Cke^{-ks}}{Y_s}\,ds
$$
ever reaches $x_0\,$.

***Case $C<0$.*** Then $Z_t\le 0$ and $Z_t$ can reach $x_0>0$ only when
$Z_t=0$ for some $t$. This is however impossible because
$$
|Z_t|=|C|\int_0^t\frac{ke^{-ks}}{Y_s}\,ds
$$
is zero if and only if $Y_s=+\infty$ for all $s\in[0,t]$ but we know that this is not true.

***Case $C=0$.*** In this case $X_t=x_0Y_t$ which never hits zero.

***Case $C\ge 0$.*** In this case it is conceivable that
$$
Y_tZ_t=x_0
$$
for some $t$.

Comment: Ah I am sorry, I think there is an error in the explicit solution - there should be a minus sign somewhere. I’ve made the correction, please check.

Comment: You are right. I adapted the answer.